# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using react-native expo i build first version of app and expo take care of that but i am now building it again and when i am uploading it on google it gives me error

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your
>   App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key

[image]

I have searched alot but there is no solution for this i dont understand what should i do to fix this , waiting for the solutions desperately

Comment: The solution is to sign your app with the correct signing key.

Comment: yes but where is signing key option ? and where i get the signing key?

Comment: checked if you have a different keystore , or your previously used keystore when you built the android app